# Apply for Jobs using Careers CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv

Now that jobs.stackoverflow.com has been migrated to be part of careers.stackoverflow.com, I propose that those of us who have CVs on Careers have a button on the job listings to simply submit our Careers CV as an application for the Job posting.

It would make life much easier rather than having to figure out the best way to get our Careers CV to a job poster.

Comment: +1 Given that there's a lot of work going into Careers right now, I would be very surprised if this wasn't `[status-planned]` already.

Comment: @Jon Seigel - I wouldn't be surprised either. What does surprise me, though, is that this wasn't implemented when they migrated from jobs to careers to begin with.

Comment: one step at a time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[status-planned] it is :).