# Directly send my Profile to an Employer

Tags: feature-request, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apply for Jobs using Careers CV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55930/apply-for-jobs-using-careers-cv)

There's no meta for careers.so, so I hope this is a good place to ask for this.

Here's my issue/ feature request:

Careers 2.0:

- has my profile
- has an employer's job posting
- has this nice button about how to contact the employer

I then have to:

1. click the button, only to just see an email address
2. copy the address into my email provider
3. copy the position title as the subject of my email
4. type up a message
5. open another browser tab, copy my profile's address
6. paste my profile's address into my email (making sure it's rich-text)
7. send email

If Careers 2.0 has all the necessary links, information, etc. to connect me to an employer, I would very much like to *not* have to go through all those steps just to contact them.

I would like instead, if the button just open a "cover letter" text box, let me fill it out, and then send it off to the employer, nicely formatted with my profile (or a preview thereof).  This reduces all the copy/pasting from the list above to just step 4.

Can this be a feature please?  This is a feature of many other job sites like Monster, CareerBuilder, and even BrassRing.

Thanks,

Comment: My apologies if this is a duplicate.  I looked because I don't think I'm the only one to think this.

Comment: Can't comment on the duplicate issue, but just to confirm for you, this is indeed the place to come with feedback/questions about Careers.

Comment: @Grace Note, thanks.  Is the attitude of my Q ok?  I took out a lot of the `why can't I`'s and made them `I would like to`'s.

Comment: It's fine. That's actually a pretty good shift, honestly, to suggest the elements rather than ask why it isn't already that way. Good job. ♪

Comment: Hi Stephen - Welcome and thanks for your suggestion! This is indeed a duplicate and I will close this question and redirect (it is on the list of improvements though :)

Comment: @Korneel Bouman, so it is!  I didn't plug in the right stuff.  Glad it was asked already.